# Resize(stretch) detail band by subreport's size

Tags: jasper-reports

I have main report with horizontal print order(4 columns). There is subreport with variable height in detail's band of main report. Problem is the variable height when I set subreport's height not enough to display all data it says:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: 
Subreport overflowed on a band that does not support overflow.
```

Can I somehow tell the main report's detail band to stretch accourding to subreport's size?

Main report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="MainReport" language="groovy" columnCount="4" printOrder="Horizontal" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="1100" columnWidth="138" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="796cf45d-4953-4dea-9173-64556d85b7fc">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Reports\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString language="SQL">
    <![CDATA[select SYSDATE from dual]]>
</queryString>
<field name="SYSDATE" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
<detail>
    <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
        <subreport>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="138" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="5901e9d7-0ae3-42b9-a804-106d502a904b"/>
            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "SubReport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Subreport:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="SubReport" language="groovy" pageWidth="555" pageHeight="802" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="a7078e79-2772-4921-afc9-de4bcd5fe09d">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[SELECT ROWNUM
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL < 50]]>
</queryString>
<field name="ROWNUM" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<detail>
    <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="10b08205-9452-44e2-8fa2-a3f782ca6aa8"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ROWNUM}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Example(EL is empty line I don't want):

```
.sub1. .sub2. .sub3. .sub4.
...... ...... ...... ......
...... ...... --EL-- --EL--
...... --EL-- --EL-- --EL--
--EL-- --EL-- --EL-- --EL-- 
--EL-- --EL-- --EL-- --EL-- 

.sub5. .sub6. .sub7. .sub8.
...... ...... ...... ......
...... ...... ...... ......
...... ...... ...... ......
...... ...... ...... --EL-- 
...... ...... --EL-- --EL-- 
...... ...... --EL-- --EL--
```

Comment: Post your jrxml code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable `Detail Overflows` property on subreport element.

Comment: This may help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660278/subreport-overflowed-on-a-band-that-does-not-support-overflow

Comment: He says Horizontal Print Order reports are not allowed to overflow on Detail bands. So I am out of luck ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the COLUMN_COUNT property for the report to 4, Set the COLUMN_WIDTH according with to the report page width (that is, COLUMN_WIDTH * 4 < Page Width).

More or less you will get what you desire.

Tell me if it's works